# register_activation_hook on multisite

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I am working on creating a plugin for a multisite wordpress framework that is enabled by default for all (by me, the *super administrator*)

When it activates it is required to create 2 tables where it will store some precedural information. Right now I am working on creating the first (most important) table.

The p_install function is called because of the options I set at the end of the function.

```
global $wpdb;
global $p_db_version;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'p_table';
$wpdb->p_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'p_table';
$charset_collate = '';
if (!empty($wpdb->charset)) {
    $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET {$wpdb->charset}";
}
if (!empty($wpdb->collate)) {
    $charset_collate .= " COLLATE {$wpdb->collate}";
}
```

$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name} (
  id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  blog_id mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  create_date datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
  modify_date datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  created_by mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  modified_by mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  is_active tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  p tinytext DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  v mediumint(9) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  c mediumint(9) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  json_data text NOT NULL,
  type mediumint(9) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY  id (id)
) {$charset_collate};";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($sql);

delete_option('p_db_version');
delete_option('p_db_sql');
delete_option('p_db_timestamp');

add_option('p_db_version', $p_db_version);
add_option('p_db_sql', $sql);
add_option('p_db_timestamp', date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'));

But it fails to create the table. Please advise.

**Edit 1**

After reading PatJ's answer I feel the need to clean up some air:

1. I got my table creation code from the [`dbDelta()` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins)
2. I have edited my code and used the **two space** policy

## Answer

And the answer is that a `datetime` cant have the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default value since **MySQL 5.6.5** so I changed `modify_date` from `datetime` to `timestamp` and all is good.

Credits to: [sebthebert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column)

Thank you.

Comment: is "enabled by default" means that you place it in the mu-plugins directory?

Comment: by "enabled by default" I mean that I enable it network-wise as administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is that a `datetime` cant have the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default value since **MySQL 5.6.5** so I changed `modify_date` from `datetime` to `timestamp` and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`dbDelta()` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins):

> Note that the dbDelta function is rather picky, however. For instance:
>
> - You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
> - **You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of your primary key.**
> - You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.
> - You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.
> - Field types must be all lowercase.

(Emphasis mine.)

I don't see a `PRIMARY KEY` in your `$sql` code -- perhaps that's what's missing.

Comment: Does not work. I have modified my code and added only **two spaces**, I then modified adding a `PRIMARY KEY` definition in the `$sql` (but `UNIQUE KEY` is a primary key anyways) and still did not work.

I created my code like the one in documentation, tested it with my servers **PhpMyAdmin**. With a hunch I just copied the example there and went with it and it worked. Perhaps the error lies within the fields I use in my query.

Comment: I did use the two-spaces between `KEY` and key name.

Comment: I found the answer. Edited the post again.